# regex for finding file paths

Tags: python, regex

I used this `regex(\/.*\.[\w:]+)` to find all file paths and directories. But in a line like this `"file path /log/file.txt some lines /log/var/file2.txt"` which contains two paths in the same line , it does not select the paths individually , rather , it selects the whole line. How to solve this?

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

Comment: Thank you . It only selects the individual paths now.

Comment: See my answer, @Sriram, if you want to find all paths use re.findall()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `regex(\/.*?\.[\w:]+)` to make regex non-greedy. If you want to find multiple matches in the same line, you can use re.findall().

Update:
Using this code and the example provided, I get:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(\/.*?\.[\w:]+)', "file path /log/file.txt some lines /log/var/file2.txt")
['/log/file.txt', '/log/var/file2.txt']
```

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer so that the question is closed if your problem is solved. @Sriram

Comment: Files don't  have extensions all the time, to catch files without extension you can use r'(\/[^\s\n]+)+'

Answer (score 5):

Your regex [`(\/.*\.[\w:]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/r7s23S/1) uses `.*` which is greedy and would match `[\w:]+` after the last dot in `file2.txt`. You could use `.*?` instead.

But it would also match `/log////var////.txt`

As an alternative you might use a repeating non greedy pattern that would match the directory structure `(?:/[^/]+)+?` followed by a part that matches the filename `/\w+\.\w+`

[`(?:/[^/]+)+?/\w+\.\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/F76qQs/1)

```
import re
s = "file path /log/file.txt some lines /log/var/file2.txt or /log////var////.txt"
print(re.findall(r'(?:/[^/]+)+?/\w+\.\w+', s))
```

That would result in:

```
['/log/file.txt', '/log/var/file2.txt']
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FVTCY96189)

Answer (score 3):

You can use python `re`

something like this:

```
import re
msg="file path /log/file.txt some lines /log/var/file2.txt"
matches = re.findall("(/[a-zA-Z\./]*[\s]?)", msg)
print(matches)
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs